# I need to create a Dropdown submenu in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation-drawer

[image: Dropdown submenu react native]

Hi guys, i need to create a dropdown submenu in react native.

Right now, i'm using typescript in my proyect and react navigation and i can't find any updated and correct solution for this issue.

I need to create this solution in typescript only.

Comment: try using this https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/menu/overview#menugroup

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago, I implemented such a Dropdown for my website. I use this reference: https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/. It is JavaScript, not TypeScript, but quite easy to convert. And should work in React Native too. Let me know, if you want to use it and need help further help with it ;)